# PostgreSQL in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, osx-server, serveradmin

There's be mention made of the fact that OS X Lion Server ships with PostgreSQL as it's standard database rather than MySQL.

Can anyone confirm:

1. It this specific to server or does OS X Lion "client" ship with it too?

   I can see indications in the file system on my Mac that it might be
   included but don't know whether they're the result of a previous
   aborted Postgres install I did on my machine pre-Lion or just some
   form of standardisation of directory structures that stops short of
   an actual install.
2. Is this intended for use as an end user database or is it just supporting functionality within the OS?

Answer (score 3):

On OS X Lion "client", here's what you can find:

```
martin$ find /usr/ -name postgre*
/usr//include/postgres_ext.h
/usr//include/postgresql
/usr//include/postgresql/internal/postgres_fe.h
/usr//include/postgresql/server/postgres.h
/usr//include/postgresql/server/postgres_ext.h
/usr//include/postgresql/server/postgres_fe.h
/usr//lib/postgresql
/usr//share/devicemgr/backend/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb
/usr//share/devicemgr/backend/vendor/rails/railties/configs/databases/postgresql.yml
/usr//share/devicemgr/webserver/gems/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/em/protocols/postgres3.rb
/usr//share/man/man1/postgres.1.gz
/usr//share/postgresql
/usr//share/postgresql/postgres.bki
/usr//share/postgresql/postgres.description
/usr//share/postgresql/postgres.shdescription
/usr//share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample
```

So no binary or similar on a default install (yet there are c/c++ headers) and rails stuff.  (note I have Xcode 4.1 installed, and this is where all these Header files may have come from).

2) OS X doesn't use a relational database for anything as far as I know. If it's there is to support development or, well, the service itself.

Comment: "OS X doesn't use a relational database for anything as far as I know". Actually, it makes quite heavy use of SQLite.

Comment: @Thilo well, but that's a different story, SQLite you know, is far from being a process like PostgreSQL. I believe you know what I mean. OS X doesn't have  SQLite server running for its own usage that you could use and create dbs, and users, and host applications into.

Answer (score 2):

They seem to have renamed the server to `postgres_real` on my non-server version of Lion.

```
 $ /usr/bin/postgres_real --version
 postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.0.5
 $ /usr/bin/psql --version
 psql (PostgreSQL) 9.0.5
 contains support for command-line editing
 $
```

I haven't found `initdb` or `pg_ctl` **yet** so far it seems using it in practice still requires a separate userland install.  I just pray that doesn't introduce conflicts and confusion between the two.

Answer (score 1):

http://opensource.apple.com/source/PostgreSQL/PostgreSQL-23/

It's used as the datastore for the stuff `serveradmin(8)` works on, Server.App and Server Essentials.

But oh yes, you have it on the client, Server.App *activates* the stuff, does not *install* it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a clean install of Lion 10.7.2 includes Postgres.

I mean client/desktop edition (I've not used the Server edition).

The included documentation suggests Apple bundled version 9.0.4 of Postgres:
file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/postgresql/html/index.html

FYI, current versions of Postgres today are 9.0.6 and 9.1.2.

Besides the list of /usr/ items posted by Martín Marconcini, I also found:
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PostgreSQLClient.framework

This was after installing lots of stuff including Java and Eclipse, but not yet doing my own install of Postgres.